# Javascript Namespace Conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, namespaces

I have the following plugin, which takes a partial game name, bounces it off our DataQuery object to get a list of items from the server (basic autocompleter/selector).

The problem I am having is this.

I am using it on a page, where the selector appears in a dialog box. When the user is done, I 'destroy' the selector, and then recreate it when they need it again. This is because on this page, the user is sometimes adding a new game, or editing, so I have to change it depending.

The **Add** ability sets the *`resultsChange`* option to *`true`*, because the user can change the game selection if they wish.

The **Edit** ability sets the *`resultsChange`* option to *`false`*, because it's locked.

However, all subsequent uses of the selector only have access to the *original* option object which was passed the *first time*. It's like using the *`destroy`* method doesn't actually remove the previous option object.

I am not seeing how I can fix this. Any help would be appreciated.

```
(function($){

    $.fn.Napalm_GameSelector = function(settings) {
        if (this.length > 1) { return false; }
        var $element = $(this);

        if (settings == 'destroy') {
            if (!$element.data('Napalm_Selector')) { return; }
            $element.data('Napalm_Selector').destroy();
            $element.removeData('Napalm_Selector');
            return;
        }
        if ($element.data('Napalm_Selector')) { return; }

        /* Verify parent element has id */
        if ($element.attr('id').length < 1) {
            Napalm_Error.failure('Base element has no ID');
            return false;
        }

        /* Verify parent element type */
        if ($element.attr('type') !== 'text') {
            Napalm_Error.failure('Must be attached to a text field');
            return false;
        }

        $element.data('Napalm_Selector', new SelectorObject(this, settings));
        delete settings;
        delete $element;
    };

    var defaults = {
            /* General */
        id: false,
        formname: false,
        selectedId: false,
        callTyping: false, 
        callStart: false,
        callComplete: false,
        callResults: false,
        callNoresults: false,
        callSelected: false,
        callUnselected: false,
        classLoader: 'dataselector_loader',
        classResults: 'dataselector_results',
        classNoresults: 'dataselector_noresults',
        classTruncated: 'dataselector_truncated',
        keyDelay: 1500,
        keyLength: 2,
        resultsTimeout: 0,
        resultsOffclick: true,
        resultsAnchor: 'left',
        resultsChange: true,
        resultsChangeText: 'Change Game',
            /* Specific */
        showGamebox: false,
        showGameinfo: true,
        classBoxart: 'boxart',
        infoBackground: false
    };

    var SelectorObject = function(element, settings) {

        var $element = $(element);
        var obj = this;

        var options = $.extend({}, defaults, settings);

        var componentName = 'User_My_GamesLibrary';

        var id = false;
        var menuTimeout = false;
        var keyTimeout = false;

        var typingStarted = false;
        var typingFinished = false;


        /* INIT */

        /* Option: ID */
        if (options.id !== false) {
            id = options.id;
            $element.attr('id', id);
        } else {
            id = $element.attr('id');
        }

        $element.parent().attr('onSubmit','javascript:return false;');
        $element.attr('autocomplete','off');


        /* METHODS */

        this.select = function(element) {
            var self = this;
            $element.val('');
            if (!parseInt(element)) {
                itemid = $(element).attr('rel');
            } else {
                itemid = element;
            }
            $element.hide();
            $('#'+id+'-formelement').attr('value', itemid);
            $element.after(this.templates.selected(id+'-selected', itemid));
            /* Change Link */
            if (options.resultsChange) {
                $('#'+id+'-selected a').click(function() {
                    /* User Callback: callUnselected */
                    if (typeof(options.callUnselected) == 'function') { options.callUnselected(); }

                    self.reset();
                    return false;
                });
            }
            /* Clean up */
            this.clear();
            /* User Callback: callComplete */
            if (typeof(options.callSelected) == 'function') { options.callSelected(itemid); }
        }

        this.binding = function() {
            var self = this;
            $element.bind('keydown click', function(e) {
                clearTimeout(keyTimeout);
                if (e.keyCode == 13 || e.type == 'click') {
                    if ($.trim($element.val()).length >= options.keyLength) { 
                        self.search();
                    }
                } else if (e.keyCode != 38 && e.keyCode != 40) {
                    /* User Callback: callStart */
                    if (!typingStarted) {
                        typingStarted = true;
                        if (typeof(options.callStart) == 'function') { options.callStart(); }
                    }
                    /* User Callback: callTyping */
                    if (typeof(options.callTyping) == 'function') { options.callTyping(); }

                    if ($.trim($element.val()).length >= options.keyLength) {
                        keyTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
                            self.search();
                        },options.keyDelay);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        this.search = function() {
            var self = this;
            /* User Callback: callEnd */
            if (typeof(options.callEnd) == 'function') { options.callEnd(); }
            /* Remove Any Existing Elements */
            this.clear();
            /* Content Exists? */
            if ($element.val().length < 1) { return false; }
            /* Loading Template */
            $element.after(this.templates.loading(id+'-loading', options.classLoader));
            $('#'+id+'-loading').css('position','absolute');
            $('#'+id+'-loading').css({
                top: ($element.position().top+$element.outerHeight(true))+'px',
                left: $element.position().left+'px'
            });
            /* Get Data */
            Napalm_DataQuery['getGames']($.trim($element.val()), function(data) {
                /* Remove Loading Template */
                $('#'+id+'-loading').remove();
                /* Setup Offclick */
                if (options.resultsOffclick) {
                    $('body').bind('click',function() { self.clear(); });
                }
                if (data['count']) {
                    /* Build Item Data */
                    var items = '';
                    $.each(data['items'], function(k, v) {
                        items += self.templates.resultsitem(id+'-item-'+v['id'], v['id'], v['title']);
                    });
                    if (data['truncated']) {
                        items += self.templates.truncateditem(id+'-item-truncated', options.classTruncated);
                    }
                    /* Inject Results */
                    $('body').append(self.templates.results(id+'-results', items, options.classResults));
                    //$element.after(self.templates.results(id+'-results', items, options.classResults));
                    $results = $('#'+id+'-results');
                    var offset = $element.offset();
                    $results
                        .css({
                            zIndex: 9999,
                            position: 'absolute',
                            minWidth: $element.outerWidth(),
                            top: Math.round(offset.top+$element.innerHeight())+'px',
                            left: Math.round(offset.left)+'px'
                        });

                    /*
                    switch (options.resultsAnchor.toLowerCase()) {
                        case 'right':
                            $results.css('left',(Napalm_Position.absolute($element).right-Napalm_Position.width('#'+id+'-results'))+'px');
                            break;
                        case 'left':
                            $results.css('left',Napalm_Position.absolute($element).left+'px');
                            break;
                    }
                    */

                    $resultsItems = $('ul > li:not(.truncated)', $results);

                    /* Binding Clicks */
                    $resultsItems.click(function() {
                        self.select(this);
                    });
                    /* Handle Arrow Keys */
                    var resultIndex = -1;
                    $(window).keydown(function(e) {
                        switch (e.keyCode) {
                            case 38: /* Up Arrow */
                                $element.blur()
                                if (resultIndex > 0) {
                                    resultIndex--;
                                    /* Release Previous */
                                    if (resultIndex < $resultsItems.size()-1) {
                                        node = $resultsItems[resultIndex+1];
                                        $(node).removeClass('active');
                                        delete node;
                                    }
                                    node = $resultsItems[resultIndex];
                                    $(node).addClass('active');
                                    /* Container Scrolling */
                                    self.scroll(node);
                                    delete node;
                                }
                                return false;
                                break;
                            case 40: /* Down Arrow */
                                $element.blur()
                                if (resultIndex < $resultsItems.size()-1) {
                                    resultIndex++;
                                    /* Release Previous */
                                    if (resultIndex > 0) {
                                        node = $resultsItems[resultIndex-1];
                                        $(node).removeClass('active');
                                        delete node;
                                    }
                                    /* Paint New */
                                    node = $resultsItems[resultIndex];
                                    $(node).addClass('active');
                                    /* Container Scrolling */
                                    self.scroll(node);
                                    delete node;
                                }
                                return false;
                                break;
                            case 13: /* Enter */
                                $element.blur()
                                if (resultIndex > -1) {
                                    self.select($resultsItems[resultIndex]);
                                }
                                return false;
                                break
                        }
                        return true;
                    });
                    /* Setup Menu Timeout */
                    if (options.resultsTimeout > 0) {
                        menuTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
                            self.clear();
                        },options.resultsTimeout);
                    }
                    /* User Callback: callResults */
                    if (typeof(options.callResults) == 'function') { options.callResults(); }
                    /* User Callback: callComplete */
                    if (typeof(options.callComplete) == 'function') { options.callComplete(); }
                } else {
                    /* No Results */
                    /* User Callback: callNoresults */
                    if (typeof(options.callNoresults) == 'function') { options.callNoresults(); }
                    /* Inject Noresults Template */
                    $element.after(self.templates.noresults(id+'-noresults', options.classNoresults));
                    /* User Callback: callComplete */
                    if (typeof(options.callComplete) == 'function') { options.callComplete(); }
                }
            });
        }

        this.scroll = function(node) {
            var self = this;
            var viewport = { top: $('#'+self.id+'-results').scrollTop(),
                             bottom: ($('#'+self.id+'-results').scrollTop() + $('#'+self.id+'-results').height()),
                             height: ($('#'+self.id+'-results').scrollTop() + $('#'+self.id+'-results').height()) - $('#'+self.id+'-results').scrollTop() }

            var pos = Napalm_Position.position(node);
            var item =  { top: $(node).prevAll().size() * (pos.bottom - pos.top),
                          bottom: ($(node).prevAll().size()+1) * (pos.bottom - pos.top),
                          height: pos.bottom - pos.top
                        }
            delete pos;

            /* Check Viewport Boundries */
            if (item.top < viewport.top) { /* Top */
                $('#'+id+'-results').scrollTop(item.top);
            } else if (item.bottom > viewport.bottom) { /* Bottom */
                $('#'+id+'-results').scrollTop(item.bottom - viewport.height);
            }
        }

        this.clear = function() {
            $('#'+id+'-loading').remove();
            $('#'+id+'-results').remove();
            $('#'+id+'-noresults').remove();
            $('body').unbind('click');
            $(window).unbind('keydown');
            clearTimeout(menuTimeout);
            typingStarted = false;
            typingFinished = false;
        }

        this.reset = function() {
            $element.show();
            $('#'+id+'-selected').remove();
            $element.focus();
        }

        this.destroy = function() {
            this.clear();
            this.reset();
            delete $element;
            delete obj;
            delete options;
            delete componentName;
            delete id;
            delete menuTimeout;
            delete keyTimeout;
            delete typingStarted;
            delete typingFinished;
        }

        this.templates = {
            loading: function(_id, _class) {
                return  '<div id="'+_id+'" class="'+_class+'">' +
                        '   <img src="http://i.rebuild.sb.napalmriot.com/common/ajax/spinner2.gif" width="16" height="16" />' +
                        '   Searching..' +
                        '</div>';
            },
            noresults: function(_id, _class) {
                return  '<div id="'+_id+'" class="'+_class+'">' +
                        '   No games found matching your search' +
                        '</div>';
            },
            results: function(_id, _items, _class) {
                return  '<div id="'+_id+'" class="'+_class+'">'+
                        '   <ul class="dieBullets">'+
                        '       '+_items+
                        '   </ul>'+
                        '</div>';
            },
            resultsitem: function(_id, _content_id, _content_value) {
                return  '<li id="'+_id+'" rel="'+_content_id+'">'+
                        '   '+_content_value+
                        '</li>';
            },
            truncateditem: function(_id) {
                return  '<li id="'+_id+'" class="truncated">'+
                        '   Refine your search<br />to see more results'+
                        '</li>';
            },
            selected: function(_id, _content_id) {
                var self = this;

                var gameURL = '';
                var gameTitle = '';

                sendData = JSON.stringify({"gameid":_content_id});

                $.ajax({
                    type:'GET',
                    async:false,
                    url:window.urls['component']+componentName+';getBoxartUrl;'+escape(escape(sendData)),
                    dataType:'json',
                    success:function(data) {
                        if (data.success) {
                            gameURL = data.response.url;
                            gameTitle = data.response.title;
                        } else {
                            Napalm_UI.error(data.response);
                        }
                    }
                });

                if (options.infoBackground) { var bgcolor = options.infoBackground; } else { var bgcolor = ''; }

                var html =  '<div id="'+_id+'">'+
                        '   <img src="'+gameURL+'" title="'+gameTitle+'" class="'+options.classBoxart+'" width="100" height="143" rel="'+_content_id+'" />'+
                        '   <img src="http://i.napalmriot.com/boxart.php?id='+_content_id+'&bgcolor='+bgcolor+'" title="'+gameTitle+'" width="31" height="150" />';
                if (options.resultsChange) {
                    html += '   <br />'+
                            '   <a href="#">'+options.resultsChangeText+'</a>';
                }
                html +=     '</div>';

                delete gameURL;
                delete gameTitle;
                delete bgcolor;
                delete _id;
                delete _content_id;

                return html;
            }
        }      

        /* Option Get/Set */
        this.option = function(key, value) {
            if (typeof(options[key]) == 'undefined') { return false; }
            if (typeof(value) == 'undefined') { return options[key]; }
            if (options[key] = value) { return true; }
            return false;            
        }

        /* Option: SelectedId */
        if (options.selectedId !== false) {
            this.select(options.selectedId);
        }

        this.binding();
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Whoa, wall of code. Great job posting all of it though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because of a peculiarity with `delete`.

And this is a hard one to understand - even the [mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/delete_Operator) makes this unclear:

> The delete operator **deletes an object**,
>   an object's property, or an element at
>   a specified index in an array.

But later states

> If expression **does not evaluate to a**
>   **property**, delete does nothing.

But if we keep reading, finally some clarity

> You can use the delete operator to
>   delete variables declared implicitly
>   **but not those declared with the var**
>   **statement.**

So there you go. Also notice how this page mentions that `delete` has a return value of true|false depending on the legality of the operation.

This little script below duplicates similar behavior to your script but in a small, easy-to-see way (requires firebug)

```
var a = {foo:'bar',bar:'foo',baz:1};
var b = {"a":a}

console.log( a );
console.log( b );

delete a;
delete b;

console.log( a );
console.log( b );

delete b.a;

console.log( b );
```

In short, I think your solution will just be to reset your options as an empty object

```
options = {};
```

Comment: Ahhhhh, that is extremely valuable information. Thank you! If I may impose a secondary question upon you: After the destroy() method with all the delete's, I ask jQ to remove the data item from the element. Is it safe to assume that is not helping because of the same 'delete' issue. I do assume that the jQ's data methods are simply a elementname -> value stack anyway. Long story short, is there a better way I should be breaking down the selector and reimplementing?

Comment: One more request for clarification (and extending my previous question). If setting options = {}; should fix this, why does it not take a new options object? Because when reinitializing the selector a second time, it is handed a new options object. Yet the original one persists. Why is that?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how you're "re-implementing", but if you use `new SelectorObject()` then you do understand you've then made TWO instances of SelectorObject, each with their own `options` variable, right?

Comment: Yes, which is why 'options' from the first, intersecting with the second was so confusing to me.

FYI, options = {} worked, thank you. But I am not sure why it mattered in the first place, since as you say, it's a completely different instance.